# Some Fields to be visible in page layout depending on the opportunity stages

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I want your help for one of my use case
I want to make visible some fields in page layout when the opportunity stage changes for different stages have different fields to be visible and those fields are mandatory to save the record. How can I achieve this by point click methods. Is it possible to do with point by click or only VF pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option is to do that using dynamic forms:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_considerations.htm&type=5
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFdpqlQV1RI

I am sure you can hide and show fields depending on another field, in you race stage. The thing that I am not sure if those appearing fields could be mandatory, but you should be ably to find out this quickly when you try the dynamic forms. Use VF only as a last resort.

Comment: Hi Boris  Is Dynamic forms are worked for standard object

Comment: Yes you are totally right. Depending on how many fields you would like to hide\show how about making one update quick action and using the components filters to show or hide this update action with the desired field to show. See details here: https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/11/10/workaround-dynamic-forms-for-standard-objects/

Comment: I know it is not the prettiest workaround but it might do the job. Another thing that I see is this Idea that might help and SF would probably make it happen soon:https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC

Comment: Yes you are totally right, Dynamic forms do not work on standart object for now. See my other comments if they can help you depending on your case.